# Fetching months all together from parameter in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have to display data on report from parameter, if that particular month is selected than data for that should be displayed.

I am successfully able to create parameter, and when that particular month or multiple months are been selected data is been displayed in report.

I have to apply one more feature that is whatever month i select it should display and even join month by too as well. For e.g. if you select in parameter Jan, Feb, Mar than it should display as below, which I am able to do it with Union all query.

Months
Jan
Feb
Mar
Jan-Feb
Jan-Feb-Mar

But if I deselect Mar month, than it should display

Months 
Jan 
Feb
Jan-Feb

Here as per my query the month Mar is still getting join i.e. I am not fetching in Mar but down in joining month it is still fetching.

Months 
Jan
Feb
Jan-Feb
Jan-Feb-Mar

I have to update the query that way whatever months are not selected it should also not display in the joining month. I am only able to update, they are not displaying in single month but at end it is still joining.

So if anyone can help please. and give me some solution.

Thank you

Comment: You will need to edit your question and add more information, there is not enough here for people to help you.  .Share your current code that is specific to this problem. Also explain or show a screen shot of where this data should be shown in the report as there may be a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @AlanSchofield.. My query is...  `Select Month_Y, [GroupID], [Benefit Type] from Table
where Month_Y in (@MonthSelected) and GroupID is not null
group by Month_Y, [GroupID],[Benefit Type] 
Union All
select 'Jan-Feb' as Month_Y,  [GroupID], [Benefit Type] from Table
where GroupID is not null and Month_Y in ('Jan-18','Feb-18')
group by [GroupID],[Benefit Type]
Union All
select 'Jan-Feb-Mar' as Month_Y,  [GroupID], [Benefit Type] from Table
where GroupID is not null and Month_Y in ('Jan-18','Feb-18','Mar-18')
group by [GroupID],[Benefit Type] `